# Solving recurrence relation using Master Method

Tags: recurrence-relations

How to solve following recurrence relation??
    $T(2n) = T(2n-20) + n.$

And if there is any other way despite Master's method to do this simpler way, what is it?

Comment: What is **Master Method** ?

Comment: Such a recurrence can be solved directly by expansion.

Comment: Can you tell me how that can be done??? @MichaelBurr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume WLOG that $n\equiv 1 \pmod{10}$, i.e. $n=10k+1$ for some nonnegative integer $k$. Then if $k\geqslant 1$,

\begin{align}
T(n) &= \sum_{j=0}^k T(10(k-j)+1) + 10(k-j)\\
&= T(1) + \sum_{j=0}^k 10(k-j)\\
&= T(1) + 10\sum_{j=1}^k j\\
&= T(1) + 5k(k+1)\\
&= T(1) + 5\left(\frac{n-1}{10}\right)\left(\frac{n}{10}\right)\\
&= T(1) + \frac{n(n-1)}{50},
\end{align}
so that $T(n)\in\Theta(n^2)$.

Comment: Ok.. I understood it now... Thanks... I appreciate the help. :)

Answer (score 4):

The master theorem isn't a good theorem to apply in this case, it's power comes from situations where the input size is reduced by a constant fraction (not decreased by a constant amount).

In this case, 
$$
T(n)=T(n-10)+n.
$$
Then,
$$
T(n-10)=T(n-20)+(n-10)
$$
Similarly,
$$
T(n-20)=T(n-30)+(n-20).
$$
Therefore,
$$
T(n)=T(n-10)+n=T(n-20)+[n+(n-10)]=T(n-30)+[n+(n-10)+(n-20)]=\cdots=\sum_{i=1}^{n/10}(n-10(i-1))
$$
(You will need appropriate ceiling/floor functions when $n$ is not a multiple of 10.  The final sum should be proved with induction.)

Comment: A telescoping series (sampled every multiple of 10) might be another way of explaining this argument.

Comment: @Michael That's an interesting way of explaining this.  Perhaps you could turn it into a new answer.

Comment: Ok.. I understood it now... Thanks... I appreciate the help. :) @MichaelBurr

Answer (score 2):

Michael Burr's answer was first and is correct. Here is another way of explaining it using the technique of *telescoping series*.  For every $n \in \{0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$ we have: 
$$ T(n) - T(n-10) =  n $$
Fix an integer $k \geq 1$. Writing this equation for $n\in\{10, 20, 30, ..., 10k\}$ gives: 
\begin{align} 
&\underbrace{T(10)}-T(0) &= 10\\
&T(20)-\underbrace{T(10)} &= 20 \\
&T(30)-T(20) &= 30\\
&T(40)-T(30) &= 40\\
&... &= ...\\
&T(10k) - T(10(k-1)) &= 10k
\end{align}
Summing all of these and noticing the cancellations on the left-hand-side (called *telescoping sums*, see the example terms that cancel that are underlined with braces above) gives: 
\begin{align}
T(10k) - T(0) &= 10 + 20 + 30 + 40 + ... + 10k \\
&= 10\sum_{i=1}^k i \\
&= 5k(k+1) 
\end{align}
So, a given initial condition $T(0)$ generates $T(10k)$ by: 
$$ \boxed{T(10k) = T(0) + 5k(k+1) \quad k \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}} $$

In a similar way, you can show that an initial condition for $T(r)$ for $r \in \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$ generates $T(10k+r)$.

Comment: Ok.. I understood it now... Thanks... I appreciate the help. :)